# beginning react: unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm just starting out on react.  I'm developing a Hello World App to start with.
My index.js is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';


class App extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <H1>Hello World</H1>
        );
    }
}

ReactDom.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

when I attempt to compile:  `npm run dev`, I get an error pointing to `<H1>` saying "unexpected token".

How do I troubleshoot this?

Thank you

### update 1

same response

```
Unexpected token (8:12)

   6 |     render() {
   7 |         return (
>  8 |             <h1>Hello World</h1>
     |             ^
   9 |         );
  10 |     }
  11 | }
```

### Update 2 - more info:

#### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

#### .babrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "leadsmanager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./frontend/frontend/src/index.js --output ./frontend/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./frontend/frontend/src/index.js --output ./frontend/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
}
```

#### frontend/frontend/src/components/App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';


class App extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <p>Hello World</p>
        );
    }
}

ReactDom.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

#### /frontend/frontend/src/components/index.js

```
import App from './components/App';
```

Comment: It should be `<h1>`. To clarify; you only capitalise components, not regular html syntax.

Comment: no change.  same issue.  anywhere else to look?

Comment: hard to propose a solution without seeing the whole setup, but it seems your dev environment isn't configured to handle jsx. jsx needs to be transpiled with babel.

Comment: ok.  more info.  does this help?

Comment: Your code is working fine, watch it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z3zda6 After you changed `H1` to `h1`, what error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting an unexpected token on the return function.

Comment: just to be sure, .babrc should be called .babelrc

Comment: Ironically because I misspelled it here I found out i misspelled .bablerc.  Wow.  ok.  Thanks lissitz

Answer (score 2):

It should be lowercase - `<h1>` and `</h1>`

Answer (score 1):

When working with React, the general rule of thumb to remember is all **DOM** elements should be written in the same way you would write in an `HTML` document. While React **components** should always be named using **PascalCase**. eg. `<MyComponent />`